# No logro cargar txt con xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, javascript, html

Les cuento que estoy queriendo terminar una web,y no logro cargar contenido de un archivo de texto en un elemento de la página web.Cuando muestro ese elemento en la consola,parece ir todo bién.Cuando lo ubico en el elemento div,no se visualiza el contenido.Estoy literalmente rompiéndome la cabeza leyendo otros posts similares,tratando de encontrar el error.
Acá les dejo el código fuente de mi página con su correspondiente js y php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Reino de la Miel</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="abeja.jpg">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reino.css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="reino.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function() {
                window.addEventListener("onload",panel,false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="principal">
            <div id="barra_menu">
                <a href="localhost/reino/reino.html"><img src="reino_p.png" alt="Logo Reino"></a>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li onclick="panel('capilares')">Capilares</li>
                    <li onclick="panel('facial')">Cuidado facial</li>
                    <li onclick="panel('corporal')">Cuidado corporal</li>
                    <li onclick="panel('beauty')">Reino beauty</li>
                    <li onclick="panel('fragancias')">Fragancias</li>
                    <li onclick="panel('infantil')">Chicos</li>
                    <li onclick="panel('salud')">Reino de la miel</li>
                </ul>
                <ul onclick="mostrar()"><li id="sesion">Iniciar sesi&oacute;n</li></ul>
                <div id="form_login">
                    <form method="post" action="sesion.php" name="sesion" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return verificar()" onmouseover="if(temporizador) {clearInterval(temporizador);} this.style.backgroundColor='white';">
                        <h1>Inicie sesi&oacute;n:</h1>
                        <div>
                        <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label></div><div><input type="text" maxlength="50" name="usuario" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Inicie sesi&oacute;n:';"></div>
                        <div><label for="contrasena">Contrase&ntilde;a: </label></div><div><input type="password" name="contrasena" maxlength="100" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Inicie sesi&oacute;n:';"></div>
                        <button type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button><button type="reset" value="Resetear">Limpiar</button><input type="submit" value="Registrarse" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].action='registrarse.php';document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].removeAttribute('onsubmit');">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="contenido_descripcion">
            </div>
            <div id="panel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ahora el js:

```
function linea(categoria,linea) {
    var contenido = new XMLHttpRequest();
    contenido.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(contenido.readyState == 4 && contenido.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("contenido_descripcion").innerHTML=contenido.responseText;
        }
    }
    contenido.open("GET","producto.php?categoria="+categoria+"&linea="+linea,true);
    contenido.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    contenido.send();
}
function panel(var categoria="capilares") {
    var contenido = new XMLHttpRequest();
    contenido.onreadystatechange=function () {
        if(contenido.readyState == 4 && (contenido.status == 200 || contenido.status==0) {
            document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML=contenido.responseText;
            linea(categoria,contenido.responseText.split('\n')[0]);
        }
    }
    contenido.open("GET","producto.php?categoria="+categoria,true);
    contenido.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    contenido.send();
}
```

Acá va el php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting("E_ALL");
    $productos=["capilares"=>["Ortiga"=>["OC103","OC105","OC104","OC102"],
                    "Queen Bee"=>["QB100","QB101","QB103","QB102"],
                    "Energizante revitalizante"=>["RE101","RE100","EN101","EN100","EN102"],
                    "Aceite de keratina"=>["AK100","AK101","KC103","KC102"],
                    "Global Cure"=>["AG105","AG102","AG100","AG101"],
                    "Henna Almendras"=>["OC106","OC107","DA101","DA102","DA103"],
                    "Propoleos"=>[""],
                    "Jarilla y Cafe"=>[""]],
            "cuidado facial"=>["Vitamina C"=>["VC300A","VC200","VC203","VC202"],
                        "Gravedad Cero"=>["GR200","GR201","GR202A"],
                        "Mango y Karite"=>["MK202","MK200","MK201"],
                        "Piure"=>["PI200","PI205","PI203","PI202","PI204"],
                        "Rejuvalene"=>["RJ209","RJ208"],
                        "Queen Bee"=>["QB207","QB208","QB209","QB206","QB210"],
                        "Eterna Juventud"=>["EJ204","EJ203","EJ202","EJ200","EJ201","EJ300"],
                        "Essential Oils"=>["ES201","ES200","ES300","ES202"],
                        "Caviar Gold Platinum"=>["CP200","CG200","CG203","CG201","CG202"],
                        "Argan y Oliva"=>["AO200","AO201","AO300","AO301A"],
                        "Power Hyaluronic Astaxantin"=>["AS202","PO200","PO202"],
                        "Collagenesse Alquimia"=>["EC202","EC201","AL200","AL203","AL201"],
                        "Propoleos"=>["PB102","PB103","PB201","PB304A","PB203","PB301","PB204","PB306"],
                        "Camila"=>["CA001","CA202","CA003","CA002"],
                        "Cellulite"=>["CE202","CE201","CE203","CE200"],
                        "Reductor"=>["RD201","RD200"],
                        "Beauty Feet Spa"=>["FU200","FU202","SP302","SP304","SP306"],
                        "Camomila Organica Blueberry"=>["PC203","BL200","BL300A","BL203"],
                        "Biopomada"=>["BI204","BI201","BI200","BI205"],
                        "Golden Sun"=>["GS212","GS213","GS214A","GS210A","GS211A"],
                        "Fragancias Femeninas"=>["FF064","FF067","FF033","SY008","SY007","FF015","FF014","FF017","FF048"],
                        "Fragancias Masculinas"=>["FF008","FM011","FM014","FM021","FF033","FM031","FM026","FM001","MA002","MA004","MA002"],/*continuar por acá*/
                        "Global Cure"=>[""],
                        "Resveratrol y Royal Jelly"=>[""],
                        "Caviar Gold"=>[""]],
            "cuidado corporal"=>["Biopomada"=>[""],
                        "Astaxanthin"=>[""],
                        "Fragancias Femeninas"=>[""],
                        "Matrix Hombre"=>[""],
                        "Rose y Pink Pepper"=>[""],
                        "Beauty Feet"=>[""],
                        "Camomila Organica"=>[""],
                        "Fragancias Masculinas"=>[""],
                        "Propoleos"=>[""]],
            "reino beauty"=>["Ojos"=>[""],
                        "Manos"=>[""],
                        "Rostro"=>[""],
                        "Labios"=>[""]],
            "fragancias"=>["Femeninas"=>[""],
                        "Masculinas"=>[""]],
            "reino de la miel"=>["Antioxidantes"=>[""],
                        "Circulatorio"=>[""],
                        "Control de Glucosa"=>[""],
                        "Control de Peso"=>[""],
                        "Energia"=>[""],
                        "Piel Cabello y Uñas"=>[""],
                        "Salud Cardiovascular"=>[""],
                        "Salud Digestiva"=>[""],
                        "Salud Emocional"=>[""],
                        "Salud Femenina"=>[""]]];
    if(isset($_GET["categoria"]) && !isset($_GET["linea"])) {
        foreach($productos[$_GET["categoria"]] as $lineas=>$codigos)
            echo $lineas;
    }
    if(isset($_GET["categoria"]) && isset($_GET["linea"])) {
        foreach($productos[$_GET["categoria"]][$_GET["linea"]] as $linea=>$producto) {
            echo file_get_contents("productos/".$producto.".txt");
        }
    }
    exit();
?>
```

Sinceramente,ya estuve repasando los manuales de ajax,php,javascript y no encuentro (qué ciego debo estar) el problema que impide que el contenido del archivo de texto mostrado por php sea cargado correctamente por ajax en el elemento div.
Gracias por toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Código que ahora parece funcionar por razones que desconozco:

Reino de la Miel
        
        
        
        
            window.onload=function(){ let miPrimeraPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              // Llamamos a resolve(...) cuando lo que estabamos haciendo finaliza con éxito, y reject(...) cuando falla.
              // En este ejemplo, usamos setTimeout(...) para simular código asíncrono. 
              // En la vida real, probablemente uses algo como XHR o una API HTML5.
              var solicitud=new XMLHttpRequest();
              solicitud.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(solicitud.readyState==4 && solicitud.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("contenido_descripcion").innerHTML=solicitud.responseText;
                }
              }
              solicitud.open("GET","producto.php?categoria=capilares&linea=Ortiga",true);
              solicitud.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              solicitud.send(null);
                resolve(); // ¡Todo salió bien!
            });

```
        miPrimeraPromise.then((successMessage) => {
          // succesMessage es lo que sea que pasamos en la función resolve(...) de arriba.
          // No tiene por qué ser un string, pero si solo es un mensaje de éxito, probablemente lo sea.
          document.getElementById("contenido_descripcion").innerHTML=successMessage;
        });
        contenido=solicitud=null;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="principal">
        <div id="barra_menu">
            <a href="localhost/reino/reino.html"><img src="reino_p.png" alt="Logo Reino"></a>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li onclick="panel('capilares')">Capilares</li>
                <li onclick="panel('facial')">Cuidado facial</li>
                <li onclick="panel('corporal')">Cuidado corporal</li>
                <li onclick="panel('beauty')">Reino beauty</li>
                <li onclick="panel('fragancias')">Fragancias</li>
                <li onclick="panel('infantil')">Chicos</li>
                <li onclick="panel('salud')">Reino de la miel</li>
            </ul>
            <ul onclick="mostrar()"><li id="sesion">Iniciar sesi&oacute;n</li></ul>
            <div id="form_login">
                <form method="post" action="sesion.php" name="sesion" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return verificar()" onmouseover="if(temporizador) {clearInterval(temporizador);} this.style.backgroundColor='white';">
                    <h1>Inicie sesi&oacute;n:</h1>
                    <div>
                    <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label></div><div><input type="text" maxlength="50" name="usuario" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Inicie sesi&oacute;n:';"></div>
                    <div><label for="contrasena">Contrase&ntilde;a: </label></div><div><input type="password" name="contrasena" maxlength="100" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Inicie sesi&oacute;n:';"></div>
                    <button type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button><button type="reset" value="Resetear">Limpiar</button><input type="submit" value="Registrarse" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].action='registrarse.php';document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].removeAttribute('onsubmit');">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contenido_descripcion">
        </div>
        <div id="panel">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Podrías reducir y organizar mejor tu código? tienes herramientas para poder hacerlo y que quienes ven tu pregunta puedan comprender mas fácilmente tu código, tienes dos funciones javascript que llaman a un script php, no se sabe cual de las dos llama a tu script php y no hay HTML para hacer un análisis como corresponde. Saludos

Comment: si abres en tu navegador la url `producto.php?categoria=Queen Bee&linea=QB100` te muestra el contenido del archivo? al hacerlo con ajax puedes ver con las `herramientas de desarrollador` del browser si se ejecuta la llamada ?

Comment: Yä lo he intentado y ,efectivamente, funciona haciendo eso.Sí.

Comment: Sí.Lo he hecho y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal ariel revisando tu codigo JS veo que llamas a la funcion Linea() desde la funcion panel(), esto no te desplegara informacion debido a la naturaleza asincrona de ajax(XMLHttpRequest) cuando se realiza la peticion puede pasar algunos milisegundos para recibir la respuesta del servidor, sin embargo, el JS no se detiene a esperar a que llegue la informacion, el sigue ejecutandose. 
la forma de hacer que esto te funcione es utilizando promesas.
te dejo este hilo donde utilizan promesas con XMLHttpRequest nativo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr

Comment: si vas a utilizar la respuesta de alguien mas, por favor lee [answer] debes traducirla y dejar los créditos del autor original

Comment: Hola.Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de asistirme.Te cuento que traté con el objeto Promise que me sugeriste.Y dentro de promise ,inserté xmlhttprequest.No funcionó.Te paso el código de lo que hice.

Comment: Hola.Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de asistirme.Te cuento que traté con el objeto Promise que me sugeriste.Y dentro de promise ,inserté xmlhttprequest.Funcionó usando el mismo código de ejemplo que figura en la página de mozilla mdn.Utilizo responseText como lo hago habitualmente,y posteriormente,fuera del if(solicitud.readyState==4 && solicitud.status==200) {} y después de open ,setRequestHeader y send,utilizo resolve() sin argumentos.Esto que hice,para mi lógica  no tiene mucho sentido .Pero funcionó la carga del contenido.Edito la pregunta para pasarles el código de lo queme funcionó